# NUnit subsequence assertion

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

NUnit has various ways to test collections against each other with [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5) and [Collection Constraints](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.4). But I do not see a way to test if one `IEnumerable` is a subsequence of another, i.e. it is subset with elements in the same order as in the superset.

Am I overlooking something, or do I need to implement this myself?

EDIT: This is the kind of test I have in mind

```
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })] // PASS
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 3, 5 })] // PASS
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 3, 3, 5 })] // PASS
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 })] // FAIL
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 5, 3 })] // FAIL
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 5, 3, 5 })] // PASS
public void TestSubsequnce(IEnumerable<int> subsequence, IEnumerable<int> supersequence)
{
    AssertSubsequence(subsequence, supersequence, Comparer<int>.Default);
}
```

Comment: There isn't a similar method even in LINQ... The nearest thing is the `string.Contains` (if you consider a `string` to be an array of `char`s)

Comment: @oleksii, example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be an out-of-the-box solution, here is what I came up with in the mean time.

```
private static void AssertSubsequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> subsequence, IEnumerable<T> superSequence, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    var superEnumerator = superSequence.GetEnumerator();

    foreach (var subElement in subsequence)
    {
        if (!superEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Assert.Fail("Expected a subsequence, but there is no match for {0} from the proposed subsequence.", subElement);
        }

        while (comparer.Compare(subElement, superEnumerator.Current) != 0)
        {
            if (!superEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Assert.Fail("Expected a subsequence, but there is no match for {0} from the proposed subsequence", subElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most efficient algorithm with worst case of `O(n log(n))`, but here's how you can do it

```
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })]   // PASS
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 3, 5 })]            // PASS
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 3, 3, 5 })]         // PASS
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 })]         // FAIL
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 5, 3 })]            // FAIL
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }, new[] { 1, 5, 3, 5 })]         // PASS
public void TestSubsequnce(IEnumerable<int> subsequence, IEnumerable<int> supersequence)
{
    AssertSubsequenceWithGaps(subsequence, supersequence);
}

public static void AssertSubsequenceWithGaps(IEnumerable<int> subsequence, IEnumerable<int> supersequence)
{
    // iterating multiple times, cast sequences to List
    var listSub = subsequence.ToList();
    var listSuper = supersequence.ToList();

    int expected = listSub.Count;
    int innerPointer = 0;
    int actual = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSub.Count; i++)
    {
        for ( /* start from where we left before */; innerPointer < listSuper.Count; innerPointer++)
        {
            var valueSub = listSub[i];
            var valueSuper = listSuper[innerPointer];
            if (valueSub == valueSuper)
            {
                actual++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```